# Rate limiting via RunBulkEnrollmentOperationAsync with Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I need to provision more 20,000 devices, but I got the error below:

> Too Many
>   Requests:{"errorCode":429001,"trackingId":"0bf62c41-dc10-42e0-b292-e95776396a31","message":"Operations
>   are being throttled for this
>   tenant.","timestampUtc":"2019-08-09T13:37:09.5244497Z"}

How to increase request rate or get around the issue?

Below is the code used:

```
 private static async Task<IEnumerable<IndividualEnrollment>> BulkCreateIndividualEnrollmentsAsync(IEnumerable<Device> activeDevicesToAdd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));                   
            var individualEnrollments = new List<IndividualEnrollment>();
            foreach (var activeDeviceToAdd in activeDevicesToAdd)
            {
                var symmetricKey = _symmetricKeyGenerator.GenerateSymmetricKey(activeDeviceToAdd.RegistrationId);
                var symmetricKeyAttestation = new SymmetricKeyAttestation(symmetricKey, symmetricKey);
                var individualEnrollment = new IndividualEnrollment(activeDeviceToAdd.RegistrationId, symmetricKeyAttestation);
                individualEnrollment.ProvisioningStatus = activeDeviceToAdd.Status = ProvisioningStatus.Enabled                                 
                individualEnrollments.Add(individualEnrollment);
            }

            if (individualEnrollments.Any())
            {
                int batchSzie = BATCH_Size;

                for (int i = 0; i < individualEnrollments.Count;)
                {
                    if (i + BATCH_Size > individualEnrollments.Count)
                        batchSzie = individualEnrollments.Count - i;

                        var bulkEnrollmentOperationResult = await _provisioningServiceClient.RunBulkEnrollmentOperationAsync(BulkOperationMode.Create, individualEnrollments.GetRange(i, batchSzie));
                    if (!bulkEnrollmentOperationResult.IsSuccessful)
                        throw new Exception("Error: " + bulkEnrollmentOperationResult.ToString());
                    i += BATCH_Size;
                }

            }

            return individualEnrollments;
        }
```

**Update**

Sample from below:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/Samples/service/BulkOperationSample/BulkOperationSample.cs

**Nuget**: `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Service`

**Result**: `BulkEnrollmentOperationResult`

There is no RetryAfter from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Am wondering if you are using the SDK to make these calls or is this your own client making the calls. In any case, you can simply retry the request. The response includes a `retry-after` value in header. This value indicates the seconds to wait before you retry.

For more info on retry-after: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-69

**Edit:**
Sorry for late reply. Not sure if SDK does not automatic retry but here is the code to do it in our batch operation

```
// batching loop
 
try
{           
    // client operation
}
catch (ProvisioningServiceClientHttpException ex) when (ex.IsTransient)
{ // retry the request
    if (ex.Fields.ContainsKey("retry-after") && int.TryParse(ex.Fields["retry-after"], out int waitTimeInSeconds))
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTimeInSeconds));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my udpate. Can you elaborate on `retry-after`. Because it is not in the result.